# How to setup Jenkins with Microsoft ADFS for SSO

Tags: jenkins, saml-2.0, adfs3.0

I'm using SAML 2.0 plugin to connect Jenkins to ADFS.

I was able to add ADFS IDP metadata in Jenkins plugin and validate successfully. This is the only configuration update I made in Jenkins SAML  plugin configuration.

After the IDP update whenever I try to hit any Jenkins URL it gets auto redirected to the ADFS server url and errors out.

I'm comfortable with Jenkins, however as I m new to ADFS I would like to know the following:

1. What Jenkins information do I need to provide to the ADFS team for them to get the integration to work and where will I find that information.
2. Apart from IDP metadata is there other ADFS details I need to provide in Jenkins ?
3. Is running Jenkins on SSL (signed by self or by CA) a must for integrating with ADFS ? I'm looking to do a very basic setup that works and not a standard setup.

   Please suggest.

I can provide their IDP metadata if required however would like recommendation of what to delete/remove from IDP file for security reasons.

Comment: Instructions in https://github.com/jenkinsci/saml-plugin/blob/master/doc/ADFS_CONFIG.md

Comment: The solution on GitHub link works... Thank you